# Join Two tables but filter no function

Tags: sql

I would like join two tables using left join, but the result is not I'm expected, the is_selected not working. The EMP_ID 004 still appear. What is the problem with my query?? Please help... Thank you

### Code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.Type,
COALESCE (a.EMP_ID,b.EMP_ID) AS ID, 
a.Deduction_No,
a.Home_Amt,
a.Deduction_Amt,
a.Group_ID,
b.Is_Selected,
From Table a
Left Outer join Table b (a.Deduction_No = b.Deduction_No)
WHERE Is_Selected = 'Y'
```

Table a

```
Deduction_No  Type    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT
 V1001         EMP                  001      D1008           10    
 V1001         GRP       G185       NULL     C1009           20        
 V1001         GRP       G185       NULL     C1009           35          
 V1001         GRP       G185       NULL     C1009          20
```

Table b

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID       Is_Selected
 V1001         G185       001               Y     
 V1001         G185       002               Y       
 V1001         G185       003               Y            
 V1001         G185       004               N
```

Output with Error

```
Deduction_No  Type    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT    Is_Selected
 V1001         EMP                  001      D1008           10           Y 
 V1001         GRP       G185       001      C1009           20           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       002      C1009           35           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       003      C1009           20          Y                                               
 V1001         GRP       G185       004      C1009           95           Y
```

Desired output

```
   Deduction_No  Type    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT    Is_Selected
 V1001         EMP                  001      D1008           10           Y 
 V1001         GRP       G185       001      C1009           20           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       002      C1009           35           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       003      C1009           20          Y
```

Thank you

Comment: I hope the table structure and relation between the tables need to modified to get correct result. Can you please point out the related reference key column between these tables? If possible provide the sqlfiddle by which we can rectify the error easily.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using.  If you are using MS SQL, then highlight the table names (one at a time) and press Alt-F1 and paste the results here.  Having the keys will help.

Comment: Please edit your question with the correct select statement. the one currently shown is missing the `from` clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL table join with coalesce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377259/sql-table-join-with-coalesce)

Comment: Please edit your question to include ddl+dml for the sample data, so that we can test our suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.Type,
COALESCE (a.EMP_ID,b.EMP_ID) AS ID, 
a.Deduction_No,
a.Home_Amt,
a.Deduction_Amt,
a.Group_ID,
b.Is_Selected,
From Table a
Left Outer join Table b on(a.Deduction_No = b.Deduction_No and Is_Selected = 'Y')
```