# SQL table join with coalesce

Tags: sql

I would like to join two tables using left join, but the result is not what I'm expecting.

The `is_selected` is not working. The EMP_ID `004` still shows up.

I don't know what is not right with my query, can you please help?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Type,
COALESCE(a.EMP_ID, b.EMP_ID) AS ID,
    a.Deduction_No,
    a.Home_Amt,
    a.Deduction_Amt,
    a.Group_ID,
    b.Is_Selected
    From Table a
LEFT JOIN TABLE b(a.Deduction_No = b.Deduction_No)
WHERE Is_Selected = 'Y'
```

Table a

```
Deduction_No  Type    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT
 V1001         EMP                  001      D1008           10    
 V1001         GRP       G185       NULL     C1009           20        
 V1001         GRP       G185       NULL     C1009           35          
 V1001         GRP       G185       NULL     C1009          20
```

Table b

```
Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    EMP_ID       Is_Selected   AMT
 V1001         G185       001               Y        20
 V1001         G185       001               N         0
 V1001         G185       002               Y        35
 V1001         G185       002               N        0
 V1001         G185       003               Y        20    
 V1001         G185       003               N        0
 V1001         G185       004               Y        20
 V1001         G185       004               N        20
```

Output with Error

```
Deduction_No  Type    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT    Is_Selected
 V1001         EMP                  001      D1008           10           Y 
 V1001         GRP       G185       001      C1009           20           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       002      C1009           35           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       003      C1009           20          Y                                               
 V1001         GRP       G185       004      C1009           95           Y
```

Desired output

```
   Deduction_No  Type    GROUP_ID    EMP_ID     Service_code    AMT    Is_Selected
 V1001         EMP                  001      D1008           10           Y 
 V1001         GRP       G185       001      C1009           20           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       002      C1009           35           Y
 V1001         GRP       G185       003      C1009           20          Y
```

Thank you

Comment: The `AMT` column in the problematic output has an `85` value which doesn't seem to match any of your sample data. Is it possible you have another row with `IS_SELECTED = 'Y'` and Deduction_No = 'V1001' ?

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this if it works:

```
                        SELECT DISTINCT a.Type_cd,
                        COALESCE (a.EMP_ID,b.EMP_ID) AS ID, 
                        a.Deduction_No,
                        a.Group_ID,
                        a.Service_code,
                        b.Is_Selected,
                        SUM(a.AMT)
                        FROM supplier_app.a a
                        RIGHT OUTER JOIN (Select Deduction_No,GROUP_ID,EMP_ID,Is_Selected FROM supplier_app.b WHERE Is_Selected ='Y' GROUP BY Deduction_No,GROUP_ID,EMP_ID,Is_Selected) b ON (a.Deduction_No = b.Deduction_No) 
                        Group by     a.Type_cd,ID,
                        a.Deduction_No,
                        a.Group_ID,
                        a.Service_code,
                        b.Is_Selected;
```

Here is the answer :

```
                            Type                  ID          Deduction_No  GROUP_ID    Service_code  delete_ind     Sum(AMT)
                        --------------------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ------------  ----------  -----------
                        EMP                   001         V1001         ?           D1008         Y                    40
                        GRP                   001         V1001         G185        C1009         Y                    75
                        GRP                   002         V1001         G185        C1009         Y                    75
                        GRP                   003         V1001         G185        C1009         Y                    75
                        GRP                   004         V1001         G185        C1009         Y                    75
```

Comment: The output is same with previous.

Comment: In table B there is a record with is_selected ='Y' across EMP_ID = 004. Hence it will come in the join. Please correct me if I am wrong. @user3559600

Comment: I have edited my answer. You have mentioned below that you wanted to combine the results, i presumed that you want to do a sum on the amounts. Kindly check if it is working fine. @user3559600

Comment: Thank for your answer,but i need to combine them based on Service_code, Em_ID and Deduction_No

Comment: ok. Let me check and reply back can you please post your desired result set.. @user3559600

Answer (score 0):

I think your query works correctly. Check out this [**SQLFiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/075e5/4), which shows, based on sample data from you that the results are returned correctly.

If you comment out the `WHERE` clause, you will get the `N` values for `IS_SELECTED` (obviously).

I think you have an extra row in your `B` table, which matches the `JOIN` condition and returns the result.

You can check if you have this extra row which respects this condition by running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE deduction_no = 'V1001'
    AND emp_id = '004'
    AND IS_SELECTED = 'Y'
```

Comment: I found that each EMP_ID display 'Y' and 'N'. I will update my table b

Comment: @user3559600 So, my answer has helped?

Comment: now my problem is how to combine them together, especially the Amt